# Fetch Date and a String from another string

Tags: php, regex

I have a bunch of strings like this, for example:

Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 19 March 2011 | Contributor: Salesman

Now, I want to extract the date and the string after Contributor, i.e, Salesman.

Currently, I am using `explode()` function in PHP.

But the problem is, the string has many variations like:

- Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 19 March 2011
- Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 2011 | Contributor: Salesman
- Time: 22:30 (25) | Contributor: Salesman
- Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 2011

I want something that works perfect for all the variations. Where a field is unavailable, I shall consider it as `NULL`. For full date I need to store the date in database, and for only year I shall save the year.

Suggest me some code for this problem, or a regular expression in PHP if this problem can be solved through it.

Comment: Do you want to have the key (e.g. time or contributor) to be returned with the string?

Comment: No, it is not necessary. I can use the array index to fetch the string, but it should work in every case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Time:.*?\|\s*(?:Date:\s*([0-9a-zA-Z ]+))?\|?\s*(?:Contributor:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+))?
```

Try this.This will only give groups available.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/18

Comment: This looks good in the demo, but when I am using it with preg_match() in PHP this returns an error: Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash. I am not aware of how to code regular expressions.

Comment: @forthaction how are you applying the regex.

Comment: @forthaction '/<regex>/g'

Comment: $pattern = 'Time:.*?\|\s*(?:Date:\s*([0-9a-zA-Z ]+))?\|?\s*(?:Contributor:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+))?';
 preg_match ( $pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3 );
 print_r ( $matches );

Comment: @forthaction use '/<regex>/g' Enclose the pattern in /

Comment: Your code is not working in this case: Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 2011 | Contributor: Sales-man. Note that hyphen between Sales and man. I forgot to mention that this case may happen.

Comment: Time:.*?\|\s*(?:Date:\s*([0-9a-zA-Z ]+))?\|?\s*(?:Contributor:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9- ]+))? try this

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
^.*?\|\s*\K(?:Date:\s*((?:\d{2}\s*\S+)?\s*\d{4})\s*\|?)?\s*(?:Contributor:\s*(\S+))?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yC6oN7/3)

Group index 1 contains the value of `Date:` field and group index 2 contains the value of `Contributor:` field.

Code:

```
<?php
$data = <<< EOT

    Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 19 March 2011
    Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 2011 | Contributor: Salesman
    Time: 22:30 (25) | Contributor: Salesman
    Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 2011
EOT;
$regex =  '~^(?:.*?\|\s*)(Date:\s*((?:\d{2} \S+ )?\d{4}))?(?:\s\|\s*)?(Contributor:\s*(\S+))?\s*$~m';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 19 March 2011
            [1] =>     Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 2011 | Contributor: Salesman
            [2] =>     Time: 22:30 (25) | Contributor: Salesman
            [3] =>     Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 2011
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Date: 19 March 2011
            [1] => Date: 2011
            [2] => 
            [3] => Date: 2011
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19 March 2011
            [1] => 2011
            [2] => 
            [3] => 2011
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => Contributor: Salesman
            [2] => Contributor: Salesman
            [3] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => Salesman
            [2] => Salesman
            [3] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: or `Date:\s*((?:\d{2} \S+ )?\d{4})|Contributor:\s*(\S+)`

Comment: In preg_match(), this is throwing an error: Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: did you use the delimiters? remove the `^` from the regex and try again.

Comment: The code you posted is not working for this case: Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 19 March 2011 | Contributor: Salesman. Empty array is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$string = 'Time: 22:30 (25) | Date: 19 March 2011';

function str_func($string, $key, $remove_key = FALSE)
{
    $string = trim($string);

    if ($string[strlen($string) - 1] !== '|') {
        $string .= '|';
    }

    $pos = strpos(strtolower($string), strtolower($key) . ':');

    if ($pos !== FALSE) {

        $return = strstr(substr($string, $pos), '|', true);

        return ($remove_key) ? trim(substr($return, strlen($key) + 1)) : $return;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

So just pass it the string and 'Time' or 'Contributor' (and optionally whether you'd like the key to be removed) e.g.

```
//Will return Time: 22:30 (25)
echo str_func($string, 'time');

//Will remove 'date: ' from the returned string
echo str_func($string, 'date', TRUE);
```

Hope this helps!